# SoP: Can Sage's take 'Natural Enhancement'?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, magic, spheres-of-power

The Sage class from the Champions of the Spheres book has several class features that let them modify their class feature or gain powers from magical talents as if they were casters.

One such is the Enhancer Esoteric Training which states the following:
"Sages with this ability may take (enhance) talents from the Enhancement sphere without possessing the Enhancement base sphere and use them as a swift action, though they may only be used on creatures or items within sage’s reach and their effects last for a number of rounds equal to the sage’s Wisdom modifier, or for 1 minute if the sage spends a ki point when activating the ability. The save DC for (enhance) talents used in this way is 10 + 1/2 the sage’s class level + his Wisdom modifier. For every 4 class levels the sage possesses, he gains one (enhance) talent as a bonus talent."

This is alright, but has one major glaring drawback, by RAW it neither gives the ability to pick up the base sphere power, nor does it grant the ability to take the natural enhancement talent, one that allows you to apply weapon enhancements to natural attacks and unarmed strikes, as it is not an (enhance) talent.

This is an issue because the classes abilities focus around emulating monk features temporarily, such as with their unarmed strikes. And if you cannot enhance your unarmed strikes the usability of this feature drops significantly.

Have the Devs ever said anything about this?

Comment: With that closing line, I think this question may've been accidentally made off topic for the site as the site no longer takes questions about the reasons designers design stuff the way they do. (See [this Meta question.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/8610)) Can this question be rephrased to meet the site's guidelines? For instance, changing that last line to something like *Is this assessment accurate, or is there something I'm misreading?* would put this back on topic.

Comment: I thought for sure this was spam when I read the title....

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Natural Enhancement to buff your own fists if you're emulating the Unarmed Strike feature of a Monk.

> A monk’s unarmed strike is treated as both a manufactured weapon and a natural weapon for the purpose of spells and effects that enhance or improve either manufactured weapons or natural weapons.

This means you can apply weapon enhancements to your own punches without any special talents, since your unarmed strikes are technically manufactured weapons for that purpose. This doesn't help the natural attack Ranger/Barbarian standing beside you, unfortunately, but you can at least make use of your own class features.